# Angular revert from 13.3.8 to 13.3.7

Tags: angular, npm, npm-package

When I run :

```
ng v
```

I get the version in the screenshot. Where does "Angular: 13.3.8" come from and how can I revert it to 13.3.7 ?

Also, where do the Packages come from in this screenshot? They differ from my packages.json

[image]

I checked the install and I only see 13.3.5 for @angular/cli

[image]

Comment: Wow that's one of a kind that different things got pulled out. Try `ng new [whatever]` again and do `ng v` inside if it will still happen. You might  want to check `ng v` from outside an angular project

Comment: When I do ng v on a ng new project I get 

Angular CLI: 13.3.5
Angular: 13.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the version report are global versions, except for the `Angular` version.

For windows the global files are located in:
`C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\`
They are usually installed using the global flag `-g`

e.g.: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

The angular version is only filled in if you run `ng v` inside a project.

If you open your **lock-file** (package-lock.json / yarn.lock / ... depending on your package manager), you will notice you will have version 13.3.8 in there.

In the **package.json** you will probably find something like `^13.3.5` remove the `^` if you want that specific version for some reason. Then just run **install** again with your package manager:

`npm install`

Answer (score 0):

@H3AR7B3A7 was correct. Here's what I did to solve it. I decided to enforce v13.3.5 everywhere as that was causing issues when not in sync

**Globally:**

Delete the C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\ folder

Run `npm i g @angular/cli@13.3.5`   - Global install of v13.3.5

**Locally:**

Delete the package-lock.json

Delete the local node_modules    by running `rm node_modules`

Delete .cache

Delete .angular

Make sure all package.json references to @angular were 13.3.5

Run `npm i @angular/cli@13.3.5`   - Local install of v13.3.5

Run`npm install`